# Datagridview not visible above Groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Having trouble displaying a DataGridView above three GroupBoxes.

Here is a screenshot of the interface in designer view:

[image: Designer view]

And here is a screenshot of the program when running:
[image: Program running]

As you can see, although the GroupBoxes aren't visible, neither is the DatagridView.

However, if I move the DataGridView to the bottom of the window, it shows:
[image]

I have tried many ways of getting the DatagridView to show:

```
resultsDatagridView.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(resultsDatagridView, 0);
```

---

(Where I mention just one GroupBox, I have done the same for all 3)

```
tab72Box.Visible = false;
resultsDatagridView.Visible = true;
```

---

```
tab72Box.SendToBack();
resultsDatagridView.BringToFront();
```

---

```
tab72Box.Hide(); 
resultsDatagridView.Show();
```

I have also tried setting the GroupBoxes' Enabled property to false, but still no luck.

Could anyone shed some light on this for me? Or perhaps there's a better way to change the interface within the same window. Having the GroupBoxes Display in another window isn't really an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think form's initialization code does something else which hide `DataGridView` or put something over it. Check constructor or possibly `Load` eventhandler or put their code here

Comment: Probably your `DataGridView` is a child of the middle `GroupBox` and since the groupbox controls are not visible at start of your application, so the grid will not be visible too. When the parent control is not visible setting `Visible` property of child to `true` doesn't make the child visible.

Comment: Move the groupbox in the designer to see if the DGV is its child. Or set a breakpoint and look at `resultsDatagridView.Parent` to check it isn't the groupbox! Also check the Location of the DGV!

Comment: @TaW Yes! That's it, the parent is the middle GroupBox... How can I Make it so that the DGV is laid over the top of the GroupBox?

Comment: There is a trick in the designer: When you move it __with the mouse__ over the groupbox (or any other container, like a Panel) it will be set to be the __nested__ child of that container. But if you move it into place __by the keyboard__ it will sit __above__ the container.. Of course there are other ways as well like bringing the DGV to the back; as it isn't a container you can then move the groupbox with the mose..

Comment: @TaW I used the keyboard method... thanks very much for your help.